# What is this MSDN warning for fopen (or fopen_s) trying to say?

Tags: c, fopen

I am trying to finalize this weird thing, that looks for a specific style of sequences in a file, checks if it is the sequence it was looking for; then, after making sure, it seeks back and changes some values to be the desired value.

It already does all these... My problem is with this following warning:

> When the `"r+"`, `"w+"`, or `"a+"` access type is specified, both reading and writing are allowed (the file is said to be open for "update"). However, when you switch from reading to writing, the input operation must encounter an `EOF` marker. If there is no `EOF`, you must use an intervening call to a file positioning function. The file positioning functions are `fsetpos`, `fseek`, and `rewind`. When you switch from writing to reading, you must use an intervening call to either `fflush` or to a file positioning function.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx

What exactly is this warning trying to say? Incidentally, I am making an intervening call to a file positioning function, right when I switch from reading to writing, using the `fsetpos` to seek back to the position I had stored.

What if I hadn't?

Doesn't the writing/reading continue from where the position-indicator was last left?

With code examples:

```
...
getc( somefilepointer );
fprintf_s( somefilepointer, "%X", 28 );
...
```

and

```
...
getc( somefilepointer );
fgetpos( somefilepointer, &an_fpos_t );
fsetpos( somefilepointer, &an_fpos_t );
fprintf_s( somefilepointer, "%X", 28 );
...
```

aren't these two identical?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the warning isn't exactly clear.  However, you DO need to be careful, because it might not do what you expect.  From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

"append/update: Open a file for update (both for input and output) with **all output operations writing data at the end of the file**. Repositioning operations (fseek, fsetpos, rewind) affects the next input operations, **but output operations move the position back to the end of file.** The file is created if it does not exist."

So if the file has been opened with **a+**, you well be printing to the end of the file.